# showSoftInputFromInputMethod is deprecated Android P API 28

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-input-method, android-9.0-pie, inputmethodmanager

The `showSoftInputFromInputMethod` method from the `InputMethodManager` class is deprecated in Android P. 
As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showSoftInputFromInputMethod(android.os.IBinder,%20int)), we should be using the `InputMethodService.requestShowSelf(int)` method for Android P and above.

Now the question is how can we get the reference for the class `InputMethodService`.
I tried creating a new object and calling `requestShowself()` on it but it doesn't work.

```
InputMethodService inputMethodService = new InputMethodService();
inputMethodService.requestShowSelf(0);
```

How can we use the suggested alternative for this deprecation for API 28 and above?

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin version:

```
    fun showKeyboard(mEtSearch: EditText, context: Context) {
            mEtSearch.requestFocus()
            val imm: InputMethodManager =
                context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.showSoftInput(mEtSearch, 0)
    }
```

Comment: Tried. Not working

Answer (score 4):

`InputMethodService` is implemented by IME apps. (e.g. gboard).
If you're app developer and trying to show IME, use `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(TextView, 0);`